# "Flying first class," "flying in first class," or "flying on first class"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Tell me please which one of the following sentences sounds the most natural and correct?

> I am flying to Canada **first class**.
>
> I am flying to Canada **in** **first class**.
>
> I am flying to Canada **on first class**.

I think that first one is the most and natural, but I have heard people say *on first class*. By the way, what if I use the word *economy*, do I say

> I am flying to Canada **economy**
>
> I am flying to Canada **in economy**

or

> I am flying to Canada **on economy**?

Comment: What do you think yourself? Which answers do you think are correct?

Comment: I said that in the question. It is the first one. But I have heard people say "on" as well

Comment: So you did. Will answer you properly.

Comment: They're all "acceptable", as is [*I flew **by** first-class*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22flew+by+first+class%22)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's correct to use both **first class** and **economy** (and similar descriptions of the level of comfort in travel) with or without the preposition **in**.

But you would have to rephrase to use **on**, as in: **I am flying on a first class ticket**, or **I am flying first class on points**.

Everybody understands that to fly first class (business class, tourist class etc) means to fly in the section of the aircraft that offers passengers an according level of service, comfort and luxury at a price. **To fly first class** (or any other class) is a set expression.

**To fly in first class** means to fly in the first class cabin. Again, the expression is universally understood among travellers although, strangely, it doesn't register on Google Books Ngram Viewer.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+fly+first+class%2Cto+fly+in+first+class